# SubSonic 3. Get results as DataTable

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

How can I get .All() method's result as a DataTable?

Currently it returns IQueryable, which can't be used as datasource for the **WinForms** DataGridView control.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Product.All(); // not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a List to a DataGridView control so just use the ToList() method on the IQueryable e.g.

```
MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyObject.All().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Product class implements one of the following: IList, IListSource, IBindingList, IBindingListView; you won't be able to bind the result to your DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

For two way binding you can use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Product>(Product.All().ToList());
```

The BindingList will update automatically when you add/remove rows from the DataGridView and the DataGridView will update automatically whan you add items to the binding list.

If you want to automatically update the DataGridView when modifying a Product, Product must implement [INotifyPropertyChaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28VS.80%29.aspx)